# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "gayumbos"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa

El otro día vi a alguien escribir *gallumbos* y le dije: ¿No se escribe *gayumbos* con i griega?
Así quedó la cosa hasta que un par de días después hablabamos en la [Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42489683#42489683) sobre la palabra *gamba*, que me recordó a *gayumbos*, y la busqué en el DLE sin mucha esperanza de encontrarla; sin embargo sí que estaba:

> **[gayumbos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J1VQ4iy)**
>
> `De or. inc.`
>
> **1.** m. pl. coloq. *Esp.* calzoncillos.

No sé cuando se incluyó en el diccionario: en la edición de 2001 no está, así que tal vez en la de 2014 o en la última de 2017.

Está marcada como "de origen incierto", y esa es precisamente la pregunta: ¿De dónde viene la palabra *gayumbos*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se trata de una palabra relativamente reciente, cuyo origen no está del todo claro. De hecho se añadió en 2005 en el *Diccionario del argot español* ([link en versión PDF](https://archive.org/stream/diccionariodear00bessgoog#page/n9/mode/2up)). La RAE, por su parte, no es hasta el 2014 que la añade, ya incluyendo el origen incierto de la palabra:

[image]

No obstante, se piensa que el origen de la palabra puede proceder de **gayomba**, término usado en el sur de la Península para referirse al *Spartium junceum* (arbusto leguminoso más comúnmente conocido como retama de olor, debido a la extraordinaria fragancia que despiden sus flores amarillas).

Por eso se cree que el término comenzó a ser utilizado de manera irónica para referirse de algún modo a los aromas desagradables que desprenden los calzoncillos usados y que podrían combatirse con un ramillete de gayombas.

Adjunto varias fuentes de interés que he encontrado y consultado:

- https://comaconcomilla.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/por-que-llamamos-gayumbos-a-los-calzoncillos/
- https://www.elconfidencial.com/alma-corazon-vida/2013-05-07/el-sorprendente-origen-de-esas-expresiones-que-utilizamos-a-diario_198084/
- https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/gayumbo

Answer (score 9):

La planta que menciona Ferran Buireu en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23987/12637) viene recogida en el Fichero General de la RAE también como *gayumba*, lo que le daría incluso aún más veracidad a la teoría, dado que de ahí a *gayumbo* apenas hay un paso. Y más aún, hay textos que directamente mencionan la planta como *gayumbos*:

> *[...] los gayumbos, que en marzo se cubren de sus perfumadas y doradas flores, con la profusión con que otras plantas se cubren de hojas [...].*
>
> Fernán Caballero (Cecilia Böhl de Faber), "Clemencia", 1852 (España).

Por cierto, en el Fichero General aparece recogido *gayumbos* como "calzoncillos" en el *Diccionario de argot español y lenguaje popular* de 1980, de Víctor León. Aunque en la hemeroteca de la BNE [he podido encontrar un uso](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000836619&page=3&search=gayumbos%20fotinias&lang=es) de la palabra muy anterior:

> Las escenas que presenciamos con motivo del traslado de los heridos tenían, aparte lo trágico, una nota en extremo pintoresca: gitanas jóvenes y viejas se encontraban a la puerta de las clínicas llorando amargamente, y a la salida
>   de las víctimas pretendían abrazarse a ellas, gritando desaforadamente:
>   —¡Ay, probesito de mi arma! ¡Destrosaíto va der to! ¡Dime er perro negro que te jirió!
>   Otra exclamaba:
>   —¡Mírale con los gayumbos y los alares ensangrentaos! ¡Justicia grande pa el ladrón, que malos mengues se coman vivo! ¡Paloma, corderito mío, tú no jiciste mal arguno!
>
> **La Voz (Madrid).** 5/5/1927, página 3.

Por tanto, se ve que a principios del siglo XX ya existía la palabra, y además su origen apunta al habla gitana. De hecho, según los artículos enlazados por la otra respuesta, se documenta su uso en 1905 en el *Diccionario del argot español*, de Luis Besses y Terrete. En una novela de 1912 se usa también, curiosamente necesitando una nota a pie para aclarar su significado:

> *—Es lo mismo, don* Rodri. *Yo no hablo como usted. Hablo como aquel que dice en* gayumbos *(4), como deben de hablar los hombres. Lo demás es perder el tiempo.*
>
> José Francés, "El sabor de la sangre", 1912 (España).

La nota (4) dice simplemente "calzoncillos". ([Texto aquí](https://archive.org/details/laestatuadecarne00fran), consultar página 119.)

Existe otra conexión posible, y es que *gayumbo* era como se denominaba al "toro que corría enmaromado", o al "toro de cuerda que se corre de noche poniendo en las calles grandes hogueras". Se trata de un toro con una cuerda atada en la cabeza y usado en algunos festejos. Pero ignoro qué conexión pueda tener con los calzoncillos.

[image: Gayumbo]

El uso de la palabra *gayumbo* con este significado [data del siglo XIX al menos](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004783599&page=8&search=gayumbos%20fotinias&lang=es):

> No hay sino recordar los tiempos en que Puerto Real solo ofrecia por San Juan y San Pedro sus candeladas, sus gayumbos y tal cual baile improvisado.
>
> **La Moda elegante (Cádiz).** 7/6/1863, página 8.

Y escrito como *gallumbos* [hay artículos](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0029048802&page=3&search=gallumbos&lang=es) con este significado de la palabra de hasta 1844.

Resumiendo: tenemos dos acepciones de la palabra (como planta y como toro) usadas en el siglo XIX, y su acepción como "calzoncillos" de principios del siglo XX. Ignoro cuál de las dos fue el origen (si es que alguna lo fue) de esta última, aunque desde luego la explicación de que se usaba la planta de los gayumbos como desodorante natural para los gayumbos es plausible. La lástima es que no he encontrado ningún texto que lo confirme o que haga mención a dicha práctica.