# ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre "recordar" y "rememorar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado, sinónimos

Ayer iba pensando en que a pesar de que el verbo inglés *remember* se suele traducir al español por *recordar*, resulta que *remember* viene del latín *rememorāre*, que también produjo en nuestro idioma el verbo *rememorar*.

Buscando en el diccionario, veo que este verbo tiene la siguiente acepción:

> **[rememorar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VtCji3T)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. rememorāre.
> ```
>
> 1. tr. **[recordar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VV3nlWy)** (‖ pasar a tener en la mente algo del pasado).

Es decir, registra ambas palabras como sinónimas. Sin embargo, yo siempre había considerado la palabra *rememorar* con un sentido más fuerte, como si los recuerdos que estás teniendo fuesen más vívidos. Si yo digo que estoy recordando un día, podría ser que simplemente me he acordado de ese día, por el motivo que sea, pero si digo que lo estoy rememorando interpreto como que lo estoy viviendo de nuevo, como si las sensaciones que me provoca ese recuerdo fueran más intensas.

No sé si esta diferenciación es cosa mía o es algo más general, por lo que pregunto: ¿existe realmente esta diferencia entre *recordar* y *rememorar*? ¿Cómo se usa en general este último?

Comment: (comentario tangencial) Me gusta cómo formateas las entradas del DLE. Lo de poner la etimología en formato código está bien pensado, es útil.

Comment: @fedorqui sí, la verdad es que queda muy bien, he empezado a hacerlo hace poco (esta misma semana), aunque no se puedan respetar las cursivas del DLE en los bloques de código.

Comment: Yo tambien he usado ese truco para la etimología en alguna [ocasión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23985/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-origen-de-la-palabra-gayumbos). Hablando de la pregunta tengo exactamente la misma sensación que tú con *rememorar*, esa palabra me sugiere que revives el momento, como si tu mente viajara a ese instante y pudieras experimentar las sensaciones de entonces.

Comment: @blonfu estaba seguro de que la idea de poner la etimología en un bloque de código no había sido mía. :-)

Comment: Sí se puede usar la cursiva (via otros caracteres de Unicode) en los bloques de código, pero no estoy seguro de si es visible en móvil: `Del lat. .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una diferencia de connotación entre los dos verbos es que, como ya se planteó, *rememorar* sugiere estar reviviendo un momento mientras que *recordar* da una idea de algo menos vívido (aunque por supuesto se puede decir *recordar **con claridad, vívidamente***, etc.). Pienso que a esto ayuda bastante el hecho de que la palabra *rememorar* remita a *memoria*, cosa que *recordar* no hace.

Pero si me preguntan (y aunque el DLE no lo especifique), para mí la diferencia es que *recordar* sugiere la aparición espontánea de recuerdos en la memoria, mientras que *rememorar* connota una acción deliberada para traer esos recuerdos. O sea, la diferencia sería de intencionalidad. *Recordar* sería básicamente involuntario, mientras que *rememorar* sería volitivo. No estoy seguro de que esto sea así para todo el mundo, pero lo es para mí. Uno recuerda o hace un esfuerzo por recordar (pero los recuerdos vienen solos, fluyen, afloran, surgen, etc., según el uso habitual); en cambio uno rememora cuando se pone (se coloca voluntariamente en la posición y disposición de) a pensar sobre el pasado.